# How to merge pandas dataframes while removing rows from first dataframe which have the same index?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

Suppose that I have 2 dataframes, df1 and df2

```
subject_id first_name last_name        
1                Alex  Anderson
2                 Amy  Ackerman
3               Allen       Ali
4               Alice      Aoni
5              Ayoung   Atiches

subject_id first_name last_name
4               Billy    Bonder
5               Brian     Black
6                Bran   Balwner
7               Bryce     Brice
8               Betty    Btisan
```

Suppose that their index is subject_id, how can I get the following:

```
subject_id first_name last_name        
1                Alex  Anderson
2                 Amy  Ackerman
3               Allen       Ali
4               Billy    Bonder
5               Brian     Black
6                Bran   Balwner
7               Bryce     Brice
8               Betty    Btisan
```

While I am at this, how to get this:

```
subject_id first_name last_name        
1                Alex  Anderson
2                 Amy  Ackerman
3               Allen       Ali
4               Alice      Aoni
5              Ayoung   Atiches
6                Bran   Balwner
7               Bryce     Brice
8               Betty    Btisan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and if necessary first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df11 = df1.set_index('subject_id')
df22 = df2.set_index('subject_id')

df3 = df22.combine_first(df11).reset_index()
print (df3)
   subject_id first_name last_name
0           1       Alex  Anderson
1           2        Amy  Ackerman
2           3      Allen       Ali
3           4      Billy    Bonder
4           5      Brian     Black
5           6       Bran   Balwner
6           7      Bryce     Brice
7           8      Betty    Btisan

df3 = df11.combine_first(df22).reset_index()
print (df3)
   subject_id first_name last_name
0           1       Alex  Anderson
1           2        Amy  Ackerman
2           3      Allen       Ali
3           4      Alice      Aoni
4           5     Ayoung   Atiches
5           6       Bran   Balwner
6           7      Bryce     Brice
7           8      Betty    Btisan
```

Comment: Wow, this works like a charm. This whole time I was looking at the merge and as @Wen mentioned concatenating and then dropping duplicates, but I knew that there is more Pythonic way to do it. Thanks man

Comment: @Wen - Yes, it happens sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

We can using `pd.concat` and `drop_duplicates`,(sorry seems like SO, hide their format...., it will make the answer ugly...)

`pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates('subject_id',keep='first')`

`Out[95]: 
   subject_id first_name last_name
0           1       Alex  Anderson
1           2        Amy  Ackerman
2           3      Allen       Ali
3           4      Alice      Aoni
4           5     Ayoung   Atiches
2           6       Bran   Balwner
3           7      Bryce     Brice
4           8      Betty    Btisan`
`pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates('subject_id',keep='last')`

`Out[96]: 
   subject_id first_name last_name
0           1       Alex  Anderson
1           2        Amy  Ackerman
2           3      Allen       Ali
0           4      Billy    Bonder
1           5      Brian     Black
2           6       Bran   Balwner
3           7      Bryce     Brice
4           8      Betty    Btisan`

Comment: Yeah, that is the way I tried, but I was looking for some one liner and @jezrael gave a great answer. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @mrGreenBrown ok, let me check the timing .

Comment: @mrGreenBrown  seems combine first is the right way to go , but it just little bit slow ...

Comment: @Wen: To get the format button back, you may need to remove your browser cache. On firefox, go to `History > Clear Recent History`. Then when you reload the SO page, the correct auxiliary files will be reloaded.